# C# WPF, Async folder decompression with cancellation support and progress

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, zip

I'm trying to create a method in a WPF client which downloads a zip file from azure and uncompress it to a folder.

So far it works great, but I'd like to add the possibility to show the progress in the UI and to make it cancellable at any time.

I've managed to do it with the download part but not with the decompression.

I don't really care wether my file is in zip format or any other format. I just want to send folders on azure as single files and as small as possible. I'd also like to avoid for now paying nuget libs for compression.

Here's what I've done so far :

```
public async Task Download()
    {
        if (!IsDownloading)
            try
            {
                IsDownloading = true;
                //Step 1: Check local presence
                //TODO

                State = CIState.Downloading;
                StateTooltip = "Downloading";

                //Step 2: Download from azure blob
                var sasUri = await cloudTransferService.GetDownloadSasUri(GetCIType());

                if (await cloudTransferService.BlobExists(CI.ID, sasUri))
                {
                    cloudTransferService.OnProgressMade += CloudTransferService_OnProgressMade;
                    Cancelable = true;
                    await cloudTransferService.DownloadCIAsync(CI.ID, sasUri, Settings.Default.ProjectLocalPath, cancellationTokenSourceource);
                    Cancelable = false; //Disable cancel button as for now decompression cannot be cancelled

                    if(!canceled)
                    {
                        StateTooltip = $"Uncompressing content";

                        var path = await fileCompressionService.UncompressCI(Settings.Default.ProjectLocalPath + @"\" + CI.ID.ToString() + ".zip");
                        localStorageManagementService.DeleteFile(Settings.Default.ProjectLocalPath + @"\" + CI.ID.ToString() + ".zip");

                        StateTooltip = $"Done";
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    Cancelable = false;
                    State = CIState.Error;
                    StateTooltip = "No content found";
                }

                //step 3: Add to local library
                //TODO



                IsDownloading = false;
                Cancelable = false;
            }
            catch (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException)
            {
                IsDownloading = false;
                State = CIState.AvailableToDownload;
                Cancelable = false;
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                Cancelable = false;
                StateTooltip = "Error";
                State = CIState.AvailableToDownload;
                IsDownloading = false;
            }

    }
```

In the file compression service :

```
public async Task<string> UncompressCI(string zipFile)
    {
        try
        {

            var ProjectPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(zipFile),Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(zipFile));

            if (Directory.Exists(ProjectPath)) Directory.Delete(ProjectPath,true);

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFile,ProjectPath );
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //throw e;
                }
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (!Directory.Exists(ProjectPath))
                throw new Exception( "Cannot find the uncompressed folder");

            return zipFile;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's how(if it's possible) to display progress from the UncompressCI method and how to make it cancellable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of an API must report its progress back to the caller and support cancellation for you to be able to track its progress and cancel it. The `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory` method does neither.

Once you call method, you cannot cancel the operation and you don't know for sure how long it will take for it to complete either.

The best thing you could do is to display an intermediate (set `IsIntermediate` to `true`) `ProgressBar` during the time it takes co compress the file.